# BindingBase.Delay for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

Is there a version of BindingBase.Delay available for Silverlight?

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [this](http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/2012/08/19/delayed-binding-in-silverlight/) extension recently. Implementation of custom binding markup extension (implementing `IMarkupExtension<T>`) with `Delay` property would be probably another way, but much harder.